# how to get the handle of listbox in vb.net 2005

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How to get the handle of a ListBox control in VB.NET 2005?

I am using

```
Dim i_Handle As ListBox

i_Handle = ListBox1.Handle
```

But this is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new `ListBox` and setting it to be the value of `ListBox1.Handle` - but `ListBox1.Handle` returns an `IntPrt` type - an integer.

```
 Dim listBoxHandle As IntPtr

 listBoxHandle = ListBox1.Handle
 MessageBox.Show(listBoxHandle) // You'll see numbers.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ListBox you must use IntPtr :

```
Dim i_Handle As IntPtr

i_Handle = ListBox1.Handle
```

Comment: Thank you. But why did your first post to -1?

Comment: I don't know , first post hazing perhaps :)

Answer (score -1):

Handle is an IntPrt (A handle is just a 32-bit integer).

Comment: sorry, can you please be clear? how should I get the hanlde in this case?